# Overloaded Function that can take two objects or a consolidated object

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have an interface, let's call it `Worker`. It looks something like this.

```
interface Worker {
  doWork(key: string): number;
};
```

A `Worker` takes a key value and does something with it. Now I want a function that calls `doWork` indirectly, i.e. something like

```
function doWork(key: string, worker: Worker): number {
  // Pretend there's more complicated stuff happening around it :)
  return worker.doWork(key);
}
```

This is fine in most cases. However, there are some `Worker` instances that only make sense for a particular `key` value. In those cases, I want my function to be able to deduce the `key` value, i.e.

```
function doWork(worker: Worker & { key: string }): number {
  // Pretend there's more complicated stuff happening around it :)
  return worker.doWork(worker.key);
}
```

so my thought was to combine these two functions into one using Typescript overload signatures, so that you can call this function with one or two arguments.

```
function doWork(key: string, worker: Worker): number;
function doWork(worker: Worker & { key: string }): number;
function doWork(arg0: string | (Worker & { key: string }), arg1?: Worker): number {
  if (typeof arg0 === 'string') {
    const key: string = arg0;
    const worker: Worker = arg1!; // non-null assertion
    return worker.doWork(key);
  } else {
    const key: string = arg0.key;
    const worker: Worker = arg0;
    return worker.doWork(key);
  }
}
```

This works, except I've got a messy non-null (well, non-undefined) assertion on Line 6. Since the function `doWork` can only be called with *either* (1) a `string` and a `Worker`, or (2) a single `Worker` which has a key, it seems to me that, once I check that `typeof arg0 === 'string'`, Typescript should be able to reason that we're in the first case and thus that `arg1` is *not* undefined. But if we remove the `!`,

```
function doWork(key: string, worker: Worker): number;
function doWork(worker: Worker & { key: string }): number;
function doWork(arg0: string | (Worker & { key: string }), arg1?: Worker): number {
  if (typeof arg0 === 'string') {
    const key: string = arg0;
    const worker: Worker = arg1; // Oops!
    return worker.doWork(key);
  } else {
    const key: string = arg0.key;
    const worker: Worker = arg0;
    return worker.doWork(key);
  }
}
```

we get an error.

```
$ tsc --strict overload.ts 
overload.ts:11:11 - error TS2322: Type 'Worker | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Worker'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Worker'.

11     const worker: Worker = arg1;
             ~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Is there a type-safe way to write this function, that doesn't involve circumventing Typescript (unchecked downcasting, `any`, etc.)? Can I prove to Typescript that my function implementation handles the two overloads like it should?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but personally I would just give the functions different names e.g. `doWorkWithKey`

Comment: Yeah, that's also fair, and long-term is probably a more sustainable solution. But as an academic quandary, I'm still quite curious if it can work the way I suggest in the question.

Comment: Overload implementations are intentionally more loosely typed and the compiler only uses the knowledge it has in the implementation signature, not the call signatures.  There are open suggestions in GitHub to do otherwise ([ms/TS#46132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46132) links to some of them) but it's not part of the language.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgL7vN) meet your needs instead?   If so I can write up an answer; please [edit] your example with a use case where it fails.

Comment: @jcalz That's genius! Please do write that as a full answer. It's perfect.

Comment: Sure, when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) are split into a set of call signatures that callers see, and a single implementation with a signature that the implementation sees.  These are compared loosely with each other, but that's about it.  The compiler does not use the call signatures to narrow types inside the implementation; they're fairly separate.  There have been a number of feature requests around improving this: see [microsoft/TypeScript#14515](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14515) and [microsoft/TypeScript#22609](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22609), among others probably. So far there is no support in the language for it.

And according to the implementation signature, `arg0` is of type `string | (Worker & { key: string })` while `arg1` is of type `Worker | undefined`.  Each argument is therefore of its own separate and uncorrelated [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and checking `arg0` has no implication for `arg1`.

---

Instead of trying to use "true" overloads for this, you could get similar behavior by having a single function signature that takes a union of [rest tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions):

```
function doWork(
  ...args: [key: string, worker: Worker] | [worker: Worker & { key: string }]
): number {
    if (args.length === 2) {
        const key: string = args[0]; // okay
        const worker: Worker = args[1]; // okay
        return worker.doWork(key);
    } else {
        const key: string = args[0].key; // okay
        const worker: Worker = args[0]; // okay
        return worker.doWork(key);
    }
}
```

Such a replacement is possible because both of your original call signatures had the same return type (`number`).  These still look very much like overloads from the caller's point of view:

```
// 1/2 doWork(key: string, worker: Worker): number
doWork("xyz", { doWork(k) { return k.length } }); // okay

// 2/2 doWork(worker: Worker & { key: string; }): number
doWork({ key: "xyz", doWork(k) { return k.length } }); // okay
```

But the compiler can now verify that the implementation body is safe, via [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis).

---

Note that if we had kept your original `typeof` check, the compiler still would complain about `worker` being possibly `undefined`:

```
if (typeof args[0] === "string") {
    const key: string = args[0];
    const worker: Worker = args[1]; // error! still Worker | undefined
    return worker.doWork(key);
}
```

Even though the check should logically distinguish whether `args` is of type `[string, Worker]` or of type `[{key: string} & Worker}]`, the compiler cannot see this.  The language does not support [discriminating a union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) by a non-[literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) type such as `string`.

But the `length` property of a tuple *is* of a numeric literal type; so `length` acts as a proper *discriminant*, and checking `args.length === 2` allows the compiler to distinguish which form of call was made, and everything works with no compiler error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkUgJbAAuEATgGYLIDqA9lQNbV6HHcAmTzbABTsAngC4kUclTIBzAJQTgAVzAAjagG4uRAL7adSGsuDxyJJsCR8BrQQDpHIKrKgSA2qIlSZwWQBokAHcWdioJW2oAXSQAHyR3ELZqCNCOADI8JC9JaTkkXSjFJBV1DgJubhIaJEFnV3sMCD9yAAskAF4upAAmeU5KwaR4SylsiHFc31lOpHqodwAGKO0hypHgMaSw1OSqWfn3AEYVwzWqCHJlKitt6nsbUOEJ+VWh3SQIDChkCrXiDZjHI+fIdOYuBbLeyiN7-YajcjBNLhJCRfZgw7LWH-C5XG5IvYPfhPUSvM7EXSGSmGAD0NKQRxpPWsxKEwLyfkCdxRaOKpQ0VEMjyEACIAB4iLAiwK4Fm2YT9WW465WViNZqyNoFAqvJB0pBMVggET4Wn0npMuVPbm7MJITKy9nTTQ6pSqAVC1l2R0TCTiyXSq1sxVIZX4tVNFrtD66XX6w3G02GYymcyWFkAIRAPHljns8w8TrkXORtuicQSNtRyPtWSLfgKRTdZX2f0G1Vq5BEMAgTBqmJiXTBIpBfhFivJg0BiPrMwxEKWpzhRGnBJ21b2BwXJxd+uoVBYAEJciQMBgN3b4iYeBAaGQIDxJ5Uw7dkUT5aTsdwPl8fgNl6us5bq4i7QhMX5DKuVZosBkJLsuL5rvcwp2J+T6Ut+Sa6EAA)